# Wavesurfer: Spotty Canvas Graph Using lineTo() and Stroke()

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph

There's this great audio visualizer library called wavesurfer: https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/

I needed the visualization (wave form rendering) to look more like a phonocardiogram, so I edited the initial code.

To be more specific, I changed the code in the drawWave method

```
    cc.beginPath();
    cc.moveTo($, halfH);

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var h = Math.round(peaks[i] * coef);
        cc.lineTo(i * scale + $, halfH + h);
    }

    cc.lineTo(this.width + $, halfH);
    cc.moveTo($, halfH);

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var h = Math.round(peaks[i] * coef);
        cc.lineTo(i * scale + $, halfH - h);
    }

    cc.lineTo(this.width + $, halfH);
    cc.fill();

    // Always draw a median line
    cc.fillRect(0, halfH - $, this.width, $);
}, this);
```

to

```
    cc.beginPath();
    cc.moveTo($, halfH);

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var h = Math.round(peaks[i] * coef);
        cc.lineTo(i * scale + $, halfH - h);
    }

    cc.stroke();

    // Always draw a median line
    cc.fillRect(0, halfH - $, this.width, $);
}, this);
```

My intention was to remove the mirror effect and change it from fill() to stroke() so it was just a line. However, the effect is spotty and bizarre.

It's possible this is related to this person's issue ([Canvas drawing with lineTo after clearRect() shows spotty lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245760/canvas-drawing-with-lineto-after-clearrect-shows-spotty-lines)) where after calling clearRect his lines are spotty, but he doesn't shown an image or code source so I can't be sure. Also there's no reference to clearRect() in the wavesurfer code so perhaps I'm grasping at straws.***Edit - actually there is a reference to clearRect but it does not seem to be relevant; more deets in update 2***

I've asked the author of the visualization tool for advice in case this is related to another method that impacts the drawWave method, but I wanted to post here as well to see if there was something obvious I was missing. Feel free to give me a general direction of research if you have an idea; I've been playing with this for a few hours and am out of ideas beyond trying to re-create the issue in a simpler example that does not include this library. So far, no dice.

Below is my fiddle which includes the modified wavesurfer library.

https://jsfiddle.net/morgwild/5sm3momk/

***Update One:***

It is definitely a different bit of the code interacting with my changes; I cut down the original fiddle to just the part I wrote and it looks great.

https://jsfiddle.net/morgwild/7x3wyhxh/

So, now I'm digging more into the original code to see what's coming up afterwards and destroying the image I want.

***Update Two***

Whoops, there was a clearRect() in the code.

```
this.waveCc.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height), this.progressCc && this.progressCc.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height)
```

However, I updated the fiddle mentioned in update one and the lines still look good. So, still have not recreated the issue in a simpler context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The waveform library comes with a pixel ratio option. It doesn't solve the issue 100%, but it solves most of the issue.